# Need help parsing JSON response Angular 4

Tags: json, angular, http, service

I am working on angular 4 and PHP, Mysql. My response from server is

```
[{"transportation_pf":"1"},[{"destination":"Swarget"}],
{"transportation_pf":"5"},[{"destination":"Swarget"},
{"destination":"Dombivli"}]]
```

Bus service and Component is

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Bus } from './bus';
import {Headers,Http } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class BusService {
private busUrl='http://localhost/MycityDB/bus.php';
constructor(private http:Http) { }

getPlatforms(){

return this.http.get(this.busUrl).map(
(res)=>res.json()   
);

}

private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
console.error('An error occurred', error);
return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
}

}
```

Bus component is

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Bus } from './bus';
import {BusService } from './bus.service';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Component({
selector: 'app-bus',
templateUrl: './bus.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./bus.component.css']
})
export class BusComponent implements OnInit {

busData: Bus[];
loadedCharacter: {};
private busUrl='http://localhost/MycityDB/bus.php';
constructor(private http: Http,private busservice: BusService) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.busservice.getPlatforms().subscribe(
(data)=>this.busData=data    
);

}

}
```

bus component html is

```
<p *ngFor="let bus of busData">
Bus works ! {{bus.destination}}
</p>
```

bus class as follows

```
export class Bus {
transportation_pf : string;
destination: string[];
}
```

Html output only shows I donno where code gets wrong.

```
# Bus works ! #
# Bus works ! #
# Bus works ! #
# Bus works ! #
```

Can anyone help ? I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

try add *ngIf="busData"

```
<div *ngIf="busData">
  <p *ngFor="let bus of busData">
   Bus works ! {{bus.destination}}
  </p>
 </div>
```

or async pipe

```
<p *ngFor="let bus of busData | async">
```

this is with Observable.

you must add  in service

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Comment: Not working. If I change field "bus.destination" to "bus.transportation_pf" then it shows data. But in case of "bus.destination" it remains blank.

Answer (score 0):

As i can notice the response you are getting is a combination of array and object. In your template `ngfor` will only iterate if `busData` contains array of `bus` object not combination of array and object. So extract response into array of `busData` object. then use `ngfor` to iterate.

Comment: You are right. Response is combination of object and array. Can you tell me how can I retrieve object and array from JSON response?

Comment: If I change field "bus.destination" to "bus.transportation_pf" then it shows data. But in case of "bus.destination" it remains blank.

Answer (score 0):

I make following changes in Bus component file

```
generateArray(obj){
return Object.keys(obj).map((key)=>{ return obj[key]});
}
```

Followed this I also make changes in HTML file

```
<div *ngFor="let mem of busData"> 
Platform Number    {{mem.transportation_source}}<br/>Destinations : 
<span *ngFor="let v of generateArray(mem.destination)">  {{v}} </span>
</div>
```

There was slight correction in generating JSON response
I generated in following format

```
[
{"transportation_source":"5","destination":["Swarget","Dombivli"]},
{"transportation_source":"5","destination":["Swarget","Dombivli"]}
]
```